# Multiple Output App

Tags: multiprocessing

Ok, so I'll try to simplify this as much as possible.

There's this game I play. So I need to grind boxes which you get after completing parties. Each account is limited to 2 boxes per day. So either I can go through all accounts, 17 I have yet, and attack and hit and get box and then do that on all accounts. Or..... there's another idea. That's where this question comes in.

I need an app that will hit the button on multiple cloned apps of the same game. The button is fixed and the app is online.

Now is this possible? Can anyone help?

Thnx

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer for you - you might look into "GUI Scripting" if you're looking for search terms. But just a warning, this type of action tends to be against the terms of service of a lot of games, so be careful of that if you decide to go through with this.

Answer (score -1):

You can write yourself a Script in AutoHotKey which you can download from https://autohotkey.com/

Writing it won't be so tough but yet very time taking but once finished it can do your work exactly in the way you want.

Here is the documentation on "how to use it", https://autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm

Let me know if you face any further problem :)